# Metallic Surface with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm having some trouble creating a metallic looking surface in ThreeJS. I know I need to use `MeshPhongMaterial` material type, but I can't seem to set it up correctly.

Here is what I have so far but it just produces a black surface.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ 
    color: 0xBCC6CC, 
    shininess: 30,
    metal: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
});
```

Any insight into what the different parameters of the `MeshPhongMaterial` actually mean to someone unfamiliar with the field of 3d graphics would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some light in scene?

Comment: As Martin said if you see a black surface you probably miss a light source. About the meaning of the properties, you can read [this](http://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/MeshPhongMaterial.html) page and play with its interface, or copy it yourself and extend it with the missing properties to understand the result

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize one could actually change those settings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Phong Shading will create the shading effect based on interpolating the normal vectors at the vertices (points) of your vector graphics. Each corner has then a direction vector which points to the direction where the surface is facing. The interpolation of this direction gives a fake effect of surface being "smooth" even though is consists of quads or triangles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading

If you are constructing the geometry manually, then you should remember to calculate the Face Normals for the Phone shading using:

```
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
```

The built-in Three.js geometries like `THREE.CylinderGeometry` sets the normals automatically at the end [of their constructor](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/CylinderGeometry.js). It is useful to check how they are building the geometry.

If you are building the meshes manually, you can also give the normals in the face constructor

```
var face = new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2, normal, color, 0 );
```

The `normal`can be the normal of the face or array of vertex normals and the Phong shader can be instructed to use these vertex normals with `THREE.SmoothShading` instead of the `THREE.FlatShading` - the later will just use the face normals.

The `shininess` defines the amount of light reflected from a point light sources - if you increase the value the specular part gets sharper, zero means there is no specular component. The reflection model is explained here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model

Because the metallic feeling comes from the point lights which create the illusion of specular reflection, you have to add some of them close to the surface:

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/PointLight
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/SpotLight
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/DirectionalLight

The all have in documentation

> Affects objects using MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial.

The `metal` will be multiplying the color of the surface with the specular light, which makes the surface color a bit darker - for example if surfaces color component for is <0.5,0.5,0.5> and specular highlight has color value <0.5,0.5,0.5>  then result is <0.25, 0.25, 0.25>  creating darker highlight component.

> If set to true the shader multiplies the specular highlight by the
>   underlying color of the object, making it appear to be more metal-like
>   and darker. If set to false the specular highlight is added ontop of
>   the underlying colors.

The `wraparound` from the documentation says

> Define whether the diffuse lighting wraps around the model or not.
>   This option adds a little more (tintable) light onto the side of the
>   object in relation to a light.

But that's just the theory, if you are interested in seeing how it really works, you can go check from the Three.js source how the Fragment shader which is fed to the GPU by the WebGL is implemented:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/lights_phong_fragment.glsl

The real stuff is there and you can see that even though the documentation only mentions the PointLight, SpotLight and DirectionalLight affecting the `MeshPhongMaterial`, the Diffuse and Ambient lights also affect the lightning and color of the surface - like they should.